# bootstrap4 dataTables search Option not working

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap4 dataTables to populate data from server. I have successfully populated data in table. But when I type value in search table, table become empty. I don't know why it is happening here is my code...

1. On load  I have used bellow code

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {        
       $('#tb_product_details').DataTable();           
       getData();
     });
   </script>
   ```
2. I have populated data from server using bellow code

   ```
   function getData() {
       $.ajax({
           type : "POST",
           url : "productDetails/getProductList",

           success : function(data) {              

               var trHTML = '';
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                     
                   var item = data[i]; 
                   trHTML += '<tr>';
                   trHTML += '<td>'+ item.slno + '</td>';
                   trHTML += '<td>'+ item.productid + '</td>';
                   trHTML += '<td>'+ item.name + '</td>';                  

                   trHTML += '</tr>';  
               }
               $('#tb_product_details tbody').append(trHTML);              
           }
       })
   }
   ```
3. I have used bellow html table code..

   ```
   <table class="table table-bordered" id="tb_product_details" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>SL</th>
               <th>Product ID</th>
               <th>Product Name</th>                       
           </tr>
       </thead>
        <tbody>
         </tbody>
   </table>
   ```
4. Here is the datatables js

   ```
   <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
   ```

Here is a jsfiddle showing the current situation: https://jsfiddle.net/035adhcx/

Please help me to find out why search is not working....

Comment: your getData() function isn't executed anywhere

Comment: @tcj sorry getProductDetails() is getData() . I have already edited

Comment: does the console show any errors?

Comment: @devlincarnate No sir, It does not show in error in console

Comment: @EnamulHaque You wrote `$('#tb_product_details tbody').append(trHTML);` but there is no `<tbody>` tag in your table

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio I have also use<tbody></tbody> tag which is not also working..

Comment: Have you tried putting `class="display"` in the `table` tag?

Comment: Could you please inspect your table to check if it is actually appending an empty tr? (or a tr containing empty TDs)

Comment: @tcj I have used like <table class="table table-bordered display" id="tb_product_details"  width="100%" cellspacing="0">

Comment: I think it might have to do with DataTables' underlying data not being updated when you add new rows. When you use the search function it looks through the underlying data, and when you just append HTML to the `tbody` it doesn't interpret that as new data being added to the DataTables object. Try assigning the table to a variable - `var t = $('#tb_product_details').DataTable()`, then appending the row using DataTables' [row.add function](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) Note: Once you add rows using `row.add()`, you have to draw the table again, like `t.row.add(...).draw()`

Comment: Also, just to note, it's probably easier to just use DataTables' `ajax`, and `columns` or `columnDefs` options to define the server source and which column should show what data from the server source, then you can just use `t.ajax.reload()` to update the table, instead of sending your own AJAX request and handling the response.

Comment: +1 to @mark.hch something is wrong on how you populate your table, I made a jsfiddle taking the demo table shown in the documentation and its working fine : https://jsfiddle.net/zn7gv3ux/

Comment: I created a fiddle which reproduces your current situation: https://jsfiddle.net/035adhcx/ as a matter of facts, it says 0 entries on this table and of course it does not filter anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending your data on `tbody` (`$('#tb_product_details tbody').append(trHTML);`) when there is actually no `tbody` set in your table, try adding the `tbody` tag manually and look if that fixes your issue, also try adding `class="display"` onto your `table` tag as shown here : https://datatables.net/manual/installation

**UPDATE :** you also populate your table after you call DataTable plugin, which is a no go as the plugin needs to have the proper table set before you load it, see this fiddle I made with the table demo provided in the documentation which works fine : https://jsfiddle.net/zn7gv3ux/

I think you should call DataTable in your success callback after you populated the data from your ajax request, that way you will make sure that your table is ready to be processed by the plugin.

So do it like so :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {                 
    getData();
  });
</script>



function getData() {
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "productDetails/getProductList",

    success : function(data) {              

        var trHTML = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                     
            var item = data[i]; 
            trHTML += '<tr>';
            trHTML += '<td>'+ item.slno + '</td>';
            trHTML += '<td>'+ item.productid + '</td>';
            trHTML += '<td>'+ item.name + '</td>';                  

            trHTML += '</tr>';  
        }
        $('#tb_product_details tbody').append(trHTML);
        $('#tb_product_details').DataTable(); //call the plugin here after appending datas              
    }
})
}
```

Snippet from *GrafiCode Studio's* jsfiddle who tested my solution :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var trHTML = '<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>';
 $('#tb_product_details tbody').append(trHTML);
 $('#tb_product_details').DataTable();

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="tb_product_details" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SL</th>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>                       
        </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
      </tbody>
</table>
```